# How to play video at exact seek time?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, seektotime

I was working on a video player of an app and I ran into a problem.

I need a video's playing cycle locked into a specified time interval. For instance, I need a video loop to play from `00:04` to `00:08`.

My dilemma is, the video only has keyframes at `00:00` and `00:10`, `MediaPlayer.seekTo(4000)` will seek the start time to `00:10` which is not  what I expected. I need the video to play at a precise time, `00:04` to `00:08`, not `00:00` to `00:10`.

`FFPlay` also supports `AVSEEK_FLAG`, but none of the flags seem to work in my case.

Maybe playing at `00:00` then fast-forward encoding to `00:04` is a good idea, but I have no idea how to implement that. My `FFMPEG` experience is poor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Jonny for translation

Comment: What units are you using - does 00:04 mean 0 minutes and 4 seconds, or 0.04 of a second?